# Why does dereferencing a string vector iterator need parentheses?

Tags: c++, oop, vector, iterator

```
vector<string> MyStrings;
vector<string>::iterator ItStr;
```

I'm using [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) to return the pointer to the string.

Why does it need to be dereferenced with parentheses?

Doesn't compile: `*ItStr.c_str();`

> error C2039: 'c_str' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>::iterator'

Compiles/Works with parentheses around iterator: `(*ItStr).c_str();`

If you could point me (no pun intended) in the right direction I would appreciate it.Thanks!

Comment: `(` and `)` are usually referred to as _parentheses_; _brackets_ usually refers to `[` and `]` (and `{` and `}` are usually referred to as _moustaches_; err, I mean _braces_).

Comment: fixed the question with "parentheses"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.` has higher precedence than the unary `*`.

`*ItStr.c_str()` is as if you had said `*(ItStr.c_str())`.

You can, of course, just use `ItStr->c_str()`, since `(*x).y` is equivalent to `x->y` (at least for pointers and iterators; you can, of course, overload the operators for your own types such that they are not consistent, but you'd be crazy to do so).

Comment: Strictly speaking, I chose your answer because you referred to "{ }" as moustaches.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `.` operator has precedence over the `*` operator.  See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 4):

Without the brackets, `*ItStr.c_str();` is interpreted as:

```
*(ItStr.c_str());
```

which obviously is wrong, and which you perhaps didn't intend. Its interpreted that way, because `.` operator has higher precedence than `*` operator. To avoid that you need to use brackets here:

```
(*ItStr).c_str();
```

So that it can be interpreted correctly - the way you intend it to be interpreted.

Have a look at:

- [C++ Operator Precedence Table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 2):

Without the parentheses you are trying to dereference the entire statement `ItStr.c_str()`.

With the parens around `*ItStr`, you're dereferencing `ItStr` and then taking the `.c_str()` member of it.  The arrow operator `->` can also be used in place of putting the parentheses around the dereferenced `ItStr`.

As James et al have pointed out, it's an operator precedence issue.