# In creating a binary tree in C, I have come across a program in THE GEEKSTUFF site. the function call : insert(&(*tree)->left,val) is not clear to me

Tags: c, function, pointers

```c
void insert (node ** tree, int val)
{
  node *temp = NULL;

  if (val < (*tree) ->data)
  {
    insert (&(*tree) ->left, val); // how will it work? bit of an explanation will be greatly appreciable.
  }
```

Outer function call is : `insert (&root,4)`   where `root` is a pointer variable of type `struct node` and currently it stores the address of the `root` node of the binary tree with data as 9 and `left` and `right` fields as `NULL` as a result of first iteration.

`*tree ->data`   will yield `9`
`*tree ->left`   will yield `NULL`.
But what will  `&(*tree) ->left` yield? What is being passed to the function `insert` ?

Any help here please?  I know `&` is for passing by reference. In that case, it should be `&(*tree ->left)`
I hope the problem is clear.

I did not try on system because I am an Engineering Professional with 33 years experience in a Steel Industry and I study a lot of programming to be able to teach my children.

I was expecting `insert (&(*tree ->left), val)` instead of `insert (&(*tree) ->left, val)`. Location of parenthesis is the issue for me.

Comment: The expression `*tree ->left` is the same as `*(tree ->left)`. The "arrow" operator `->` have higher [*precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator `*`.

Comment: `&(*tree) ->left` is equal to `&((*tree)->left)`, not `&(*tree->left)`, because the `&`, `*` operators' precedence makes them apply to the whole expression, not just to `tree` if you omit the parentheses. What this is doing is passing to `insert` a pointer to the pointer `tree->left`. This is a pointer to the contents of the root node, not to the left tree. So it could be used to change which tree is on the left, not by changing the left tree itself, but by changing which one is pointed to by the root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does dereferencing a string vector iterator need parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780149/why-does-dereferencing-a-string-vector-iterator-need-parentheses)